# Complexity of variant polynomial factorization

Tags: polynomials, np-complete

Few years back a [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4769/an-np-complete-variant-of-factoring?rq=1) on whether a variant of integer factorization was $\mathsf{NP}$ complete was asked, which according to state of mathematics today does not have a conclusive answer.

Is following variant of polynomial factorization, 'given $p(x)\in\Bbb Z[x], l,u\in\Bbb N$, is there a $q(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$ with $l\leq\mathsf{deg}(q(x))\leq u$ such that $q(x)|p(x)$', $\mathsf{NP}$ complete?

Comment: No, it's in P. Factoring of polynomials over $\mathbb Z$ into irreducible factors (except constant factors) can be done in polynomial-time by LLL, and then the question reduces to checking if a subset of the degrees of the irreducible factors sums to a number between $l$ and $u$, which is easy as they have a unary bound.

Comment: what is an unary bound?

Comment: A bound that can be written in unary. Here, wlog $u$ is at most the degree of $p$.

Comment: Oh the issue here is we have atmost $O(p)$ distinct degree of factors and checking certain subset of degrees sum in between $l$ and $u$ can be done in $O(p^c)$ time for some fixed constant $c>1$? This is in poly time?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution