# Consequences of polynomial time algorithm to variant of integer factorization

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, nt.number-theory, np-complete, factoring, undecidability

Given $N,U,V\in\Bbb N$ is there $n\in[U,V]\cap\Bbb N$ such that $n|N$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete modulo Cramer's conjecture on prime gaps is shown in [An NP-complete variant of factoring.](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4769/an-np-complete-variant-of-factoring)

So supposing status of Cramer's conjecture remains uncertain (that is it is not known to be true/false or undecidable), then is there any consequence of polynomial time algorithm to this variant factoring problem assuming that Cramer's conjecture cannot be removed from the reduction? That is could such an algorithm be of any value other than breaking RSA and some number theory problems? Could we use this algorithm to solve other problems in $\mathsf{NP}$. Would this still imply at least $\mathsf{NP}\subseteq\mathsf{RP}$? Where in Impagliazzo's five worlds would we be in?

**Update:** What is minimum number of distinct primes one needs in $N$ for completeness of this problem under Cramer's conjecture? How many such numbers are there?

Comment: Why would Cramer's conjecture need to be true? $\;$

Comment: I have a modified cramer's conjecture (note that I have used $k$-almost prime instead of prime). Read comments in attached stackexchange link.

Comment: Can you be more specific? $\;\;\;$ There are 49 comments at that link, and I have no clue how any of them would yield implications _from_ $\:$ P = NP $\;$. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: If $P=NP$, then there is a deterministic reduction from subset sum to this problem. Shouldn't this say gaps of primes are small? I could be wrong. This is the reasoning.

Comment: No. $\:$ Such a reduction could just consist of solving the subset sum instance and then outputting some otherwise-arbitrary instance of this problem with the same answer. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I think removing Cramer's conjecture in the reduction is unlikely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZPP = NP ​ is a "consequence of polynomial time algorithm to this variant factoring problem", which can be deduced by *replacing* Cramer's conjecture with zero-error randomness,

rather than just *removing* Cramer's conjecture. ​ ​ ​ ​ Accordingly, we would be in Algorithmica.

One can simply test *randomly chosen* numbers in [the relevant intervals](https://mathoverflow.net/q/212816/5810)

for primality, rather than choosing them deterministically.

Unless ​ NP $\hspace{-0.02 in}\subseteq$ [BQ](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:B#bqp)S[UBEXP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:S#subexp) ​ infinitely often, one needs [input_length][$^{\hspace{.03 in}\Omega \hspace{.02 in}(1)}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#The_Knuth_definition) distinct primes

"in $N$ for completeness of this problem under Cramer's conjecture",

since Shor's algorithm can be used to *find* the prime factors, and given those,

this problem can be solved by trying the products of each sub[multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) of those primes.

There are lots of such numbers, since there are lots of primes.

Products of n distinct $\big[$primes less than $2^{\hspace{.02 in}n}\hspace{-0.03 in}\big]$ are less than $2^{\hspace{.02 in}n^2}\hspace{-0.06 in}$, so their number of distinct prime factors is not less than [their_length]$^{1/2}$. ​ ​ ​ ​ [According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function), since 2 is the only power of 2 that's prime, if ​ 6 ≤ n ​ then $\big[$the number of primes less than $2^{\hspace{.02 in}n}\hspace{-0.03 in}\big]$ is greater than $\dfrac{2^{\hspace{.02 in}n}}{\ln \hspace{-0.03 in}\left(2^{\hspace{.02 in}n}\right)\hspace{-0.03 in}+\hspace{-0.03 in}2}$.

For all n, if ​ 20 ≤ n ​ then $\ln \hspace{-0.03 in}\left(2^{\hspace{.02 in}n}\right)\hspace{-0.03 in}+\hspace{-0.03 in}2 \: = \: (n\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}\ln(2))+2 \: = \: (\ln(2)\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}n)+2 \: < \: \Big(\hspace{-0.05 in}\frac7{10}\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}n\hspace{-0.04 in}\Big)+2 \: \leq \: \Big(\hspace{-0.05 in}\frac7{10}\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}n\hspace{-0.04 in}\Big)+\Big(\hspace{-0.05 in}\frac1{10}\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}n\hspace{-0.04 in}\Big) \: = \: \frac45 \cdot n \;\;\;$.

For all n, if ​ 20 ≤ n ​ then $\: \dfrac{5\hspace{-0.05 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.05 in}\left(2^{\hspace{.02 in}n-2}\hspace{-0.05 in}\right)}n = \dfrac{\frac54 \hspace{-0.05 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in} 2^{\hspace{.02 in}n}}n = \dfrac{2^{\hspace{.02 in}n}}{\frac45 \hspace{-0.05 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}n} < \dfrac{2^{\hspace{.02 in}n}}{\ln \hspace{-0.03 in}\left(2^{\hspace{.02 in}n}\right)\hspace{-0.03 in}+\hspace{-0.03 in}2}$.

For all n, if ​ 20 ≤ n ​ then there are more than $\dfrac{5\hspace{-0.05 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.05 in}\left(2^{\hspace{.02 in}n-2}\hspace{-0.05 in}\right)}n$ primes less than $2^{\hspace{.02 in}n}$.

For each such n, one can choose n disjoint sets of at least $\left\lfloor \hspace{-0.05 in} \dfrac{5\hspace{-0.05 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.05 in}\left(2^{\hspace{.02 in}n-2}\hspace{-0.05 in}\right)}{n^{\hspace{.02 in}2}}\hspace{-0.04 in} \right\rfloor$ of those primes.

For all n, if ​ 20 ≤ n ​ then $\;\;\; \dfrac{2^{\hspace{.02 in}n}}{n^{\hspace{.02 in}2}} \: = \: \dfrac{4\hspace{-0.05 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.05 in}\left(2^{\hspace{.02 in}n-2}\hspace{-0.05 in}\right)}{n^{\hspace{.02 in}2}} \: < \: \dfrac{\left(4\hspace{-0.05 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.05 in}\left(2^{\hspace{.02 in}n-2}\hspace{-0.05 in}\right)\right)+2^{\hspace{.02 in}n-2}\hspace{-0.04 in}-n^2}{n^{\hspace{.02 in}2}}$

$= \: \dfrac{4\hspace{-0.05 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.05 in}\left(2^{\hspace{.02 in}n-2}\hspace{-0.05 in}\right)}{n^{\hspace{.02 in}2}} \: < \: \dfrac{\left(5\hspace{-0.05 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.05 in}\left(2^{\hspace{.02 in}n-2}\hspace{-0.05 in}\right)\right)\hspace{-0.02 in}-n^2}{n^{\hspace{.02 in}2}} \: = \: \dfrac{5\hspace{-0.05 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.05 in}\left(2^{\hspace{.02 in}n-2}\hspace{-0.05 in}\right)}{n^{\hspace{.02 in}2}}-1 \: < \: \left\lfloor \hspace{-0.05 in} \dfrac{5\hspace{-0.05 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.05 in}\left(2^{\hspace{.02 in}n-2}\hspace{-0.05 in}\right)}{n^{\hspace{.02 in}2}}\hspace{-0.04 in} \right\rfloor \;\;\;$.

For all n, if ​ 20 ≤ n ​ then one can choose n disjoint sets of at least $\dfrac{2^{\hspace{.02 in}n}}{n^{\hspace{.02 in}2}}$ primes less than $2^{\hspace{.02 in}n}$.

For all n, if ​ 20 ≤ n ​ then at least $\bigg(\hspace{-0.04 in}\dfrac{2^{\hspace{.02 in}n}}{n^{\hspace{.02 in}2}}\hspace{-0.06 in}\bigg)^{\hspace{-0.04 in}n}$ number less than $2^{\hspace{.02 in}n^2}$ have n distinct prime factors.

For all n, $\; \bigg(\hspace{-0.04 in}\dfrac{2^{\hspace{.02 in}n}}{n^{\hspace{.02 in}2}}\hspace{-0.06 in}\bigg)^{\hspace{-0.04 in}n} = \dfrac{\left(2^{\hspace{.02 in}n}\hspace{-0.02 in}\right)^n}{\left(\hspace{-0.02 in}n^{\hspace{.02 in}2}\hspace{-0.04 in}\right)^{\hspace{-0.02 in}n}} = \dfrac{2^{\hspace{.02 in}n\cdot n}}{n^{\hspace{.02 in}2\cdot n}} = \dfrac{2^{\hspace{.02 in}n^2}}{n^{\hspace{.02 in}2\cdot n}} \:\:$.

Therefore, for all n, if ​ 20 ≤ n ​ then at least $\dfrac{2^{\hspace{.02 in}n^2}}{n^{\hspace{.02 in}2\cdot n}}$ numbers less than $2^{\hspace{.02 in}n^2}$ are

such that their number of distinct prime factors is not less than [their_length]$^{1/2}$.

Comment: do you mean this http://mathoverflow.net/questions/212816/are-there-effective-small-intervals-in-which-primes-are-dense? Could you add your knowledge on replacing Cramer's conjecture in a more down to earth way?

Comment: What is the definition of an 'effective result'?

Comment: I believe 'effective result' is defined in the same way as "constructive result", although the term 'effective' would be used far less often in [continuous math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_analysis). ​ ​

Comment: Could you give an estimate on 'lots of such numbers'? Your 'effective' result is still vague otherwise I am happy with your post.

Comment: ah ever in you use 'zero error randomness' instead of cramer's conjecture, do you have implication $NP\subseteq BQSUBEXP$ if number of distinct primes is much smaller than quoted estimate in your post?

Comment: Yes. ​ Even ZPP can carry out the reduction, so BQSUBEXP can also carry out the reduction. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: should be "even if".

Comment: So supposing this problem is in $P/Poly$, then does $NP\subseteq P/Poly$ hold (since $ZPP\subseteq BPP\subseteq P/Poly$ holds)?

Comment: Well, I think the mere results $\: ZPP\subseteq BPP\subset P/poly \:$ aren't enough, but from the _proof_ of $\: BPP\subseteq P/poly \:$, $\:$ one can conclude that $\: NP\subseteq P/poly \:$ would hold if this problem is in $P/poly$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: That is right, but there is no analogue in Impagliazzo's world right? This would be something else?

Comment: "there is no analogue" of what "in Impagliazzo's world"s? $\;$

Comment: Analogue to fact $NP\subseteq P/Poly$ or similar hierarchy collapse results?

Comment: The analogue to $\: NP \subseteq P/poly \:$ for Impagliazzo's worlds would be that we're not in Minicrypt or Cryptomania with respect to non-uniform adversaries. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: As you mentioned we need [input_length][$^{\hspace{.03 in}\Omega \hspace{.02 in}(1)}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#The_Knuth_definition) distinct primes. If [input length] is $\log_2 n$ bits, could the primes be as small as [${\hspace{.03 in}o\hspace{.02 in}((\log_2 n)^{\frac1k})}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#The_Knuth_definition) where $6>(\log_2 n)^{\frac1k}$ or $k>\frac{\log_2(\log_2n)}{\log_26}$?

Comment: Those conditions each force $k$ to converge to $\infty$. $\;$

Comment: So what? Is there an issue?

Comment: Yes, since only $\:o\hspace{-0.04 in}\left(\hspace{-0.05 in}(\log(n))^{\frac1k}\hspace{-0.07 in}\right)\:$ primes are as small as $\:o\hspace{-0.04 in}\left(\hspace{-0.05 in}(\log(n))^{\frac1k}\hspace{-0.07 in}\right)\;$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: yes that is indeed correct. so how small can the primes be if all are of same size?

Comment: Their lengths can be polynomial in the input's length. $\;$

Comment: I dont get it. Say input number $N$ has $\log N$ bits. And $N=p_1^{e_1}\dots p_t^{e_1}$. You mentioned $t=(\log N)^{\Omega(1)}$. How can each prime be of length $\log p_i=(\log N)^{\Omega(1)}$ as well?

Comment: I was referring to the reduction, where "the input" is the instance of an NP problem. $\hspace{.44 in}$ (Although, actually, that doesn't matter, since the number of primes could just $\hspace{1.16 in}$ be the same as the length of each prime.) $\;$

Comment: That is why I am wondering what is the largest size of primes if all primes are of equal size (for case $e_i=1$) for the reduction to still hold NP hardness?

Comment: @RickyDemer Do you know how big $\log_2U-\log_2L$ can be for the problem to remainNP complete if Cramer's conjecture holds true? Is the difference bounded above by constants?