# On variant of integer factorization

Tags: np-complete, factoring

In the [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4769/an-np-complete-variant-of-factoring?rq=1) on whether a variant of integer factorization
$$\mathsf{}\mbox{ }{\Pi} = \{\langle a, b, n \rangle \;|\; \exists \mbox{ } \mathsf{ an}\mbox{ }\mathsf{ integer}\mbox{ } m \in \{a, \ldots, b\}\mbox{ }\mathsf{ such}\mbox{ }\mathsf{that}\mbox{ }m | n\}$$
 is $\mathsf{NP}$ complete, it is clear that difference $b-a$ can neither be too small nor too big for the problem to remain $\mathsf{NP}$ complete under Cramér's conjecture. What is the possible range of difference $b-a$ under which the problem remains $\mathsf{NP}$ complete under Cramér's conjecture?

*Note.* [Cramér's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r's_conjecture) states that the difference between two consecutive prime numbers $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$ is asymptotically $O(\log^2 p_n)$.