# An NP-complete variant of factoring and relation to factoring

Tags: np, np-complete, factoring

After reading this post [An NP-complete variant of factoring.](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4769/an-np-complete-variant-of-factoring) I come up with a question.

To summerize the post, we have the factoring problem (F) which ask for a number $p$ that is prime and divides an given number n and $p$ is between a given interval $l \leq $p$ \leq u$. The variant of the factoring problem (VF) ask for a number $p$ that divides an given number n and $p$ is in the interval $l \leq $p$ \leq u$, but not necessarily needs to be prime. So while (F) is not believed to be NP-complete, (VF) is.

But couldn't you solve (VF) with polynominal many oracle calls to (F), by first getting all prime divisors of n. (This list, lets call it l, has at most $log_2(n)$ many entries)
Then calculate all subset products of $l$. An upper bound for how many this could be, would be given by the number of ways of choosing $i$ many elements from $l$, for $i = 0$ to $log_2(n)$. So $\sum_{i = 0}^{log_2(n)} \binom{log_2(n)}{i} =  2^{log_2(n)} = n$. So there also polynominal many products, which needs to be checked if they are between $l$ and $u$.

Wouldn't this make Factoring also NP-complete?

Comment: i think the error is that there a exponentiell number of products, since it is $n$.

Comment: It seems you answered your own question.

Comment: @user3680510 It can be shown you have up to $2^{c\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}}$ for some fixed $c>0$ and related problem is here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/222392/on-variant-of-integer-factorization.